# Save and update current date , daily in sqlite android

Tags: android, date, sql-update, android-sqlite

I have a date column in my sqlite database android. 
First time I insert date through this

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

 cv.put(DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy ").format(new Date()));


return ourDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(MY_DAILYTABLE, null, cv,
            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

now this way I just get the current date. But it remain same next day when the actual date changes. because I am not updating it.

Problem : Can anybody guide me how can I update the date every day to the current system date? So that my app shows 21/10/2014 today and 22/10/2014 tomorrow and so on.

Comment: Does your app have any receivers that get triggered daily ?

Comment: I have not done this. I want this functionality in my app. To get daily triggers. and take daily user data and store it in  sqlite.Can you guide me how to do it?

Comment: you should use Alarms & Receivers in Android to trigger an alarm every day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of your app's activity or if you have a class that extends Application , you need to set an alarm to run daily using alarm manager : https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

After you've done this in your BroadcastReceiver ( the one you registered with your alarm manager ), simply get an instance to calendar and save data in your DB.

Do this in your AlarmReceiver.class

```
Calendar calendar;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null) {
        return;
    }

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy ").format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()))
```

Comment: Right I can do this. But how can I update my Date column daily? what should I do for updating date?